# working directory is not a cordova project

Tags: vue.js, cordova, npm, html-framework-7

After running `npm run build-prod-cordova-android` in my framework7 vue project my build is successful but I get this error just before my Cordova build:

Current working directory is not a Cordova-based project.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! sekani@1.0.0 build-prod-cordova-android: `cross-env TARGET=cordova cross-env NODE_ENV=production node ./build/build.js && cd cordova && cordova build android`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the sekani@1.0.0 build-prod-cordova-android script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

This is my current project structure
[image]

Kindly indicate what is wrong and possible solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue of this to be that the Cordova directory was missing the `www/` folder so Cordova won't run, then again Framework7 setup this package for the build to be generated in the `build` folder.

I would advise you not to redirect your build(especially if you are not familiar with how to do it) rather you could copy the `www/` folder in `build/cordova` and paste it into your Cordova project directory and build your apk from there.

Answer (score 0):

For others who face this issue but have a www/ folder:

Cordova looks for a `www` directory, `platforms` directory and `config.xml` file starting in the current working directory and then up the tree to the root folder.

Specific code is in:

```
%appdata%\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\util.js
```

(Your Cordova installation folder might be elsewhere)